# Rails Converting from Timestamp to Formatted Time with Timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building an application using Rails 4. I'm reading a Unix timestamp from JSON and attempting to display it as a properly formatted time according to my timezone. I'm able to read the display the timestamp, but it is displayed in UTC instead of EST.

This is what I have in my view

```
<%= Time.at(DateTime.strptime(@weather['sys']['sunrise'].to_s,'%s')).strftime("%l:%M %P") %>
```

I have four different timestamps where I am doing this same conversion.

Is there something I can tack on to this to display the proper time zone?

Comment: `in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")` or `in_time_zone("EST")`  - have you tried this with your current time format ? Example: `Time.now.in_time_zone("EST")`

Comment: I had tried that @dkp and I was getting the whole datetime printed as 2016-03-29 11:18:00 -0400 so I wasn't sure if this was the right track or not. I just tried it again and switched things around to convert to timezone before formatting and it worked! This is what I used: <%= Time.at(DateTime.strptime(@weather['sys']['sunrise'].to_s,'%s')).in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").strftime("%l:%M %P") %> If you want to write that up as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for putting me on the right track!

Comment: glad that it helped you! Updated it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<%= Time.at(DateTime.strptime(@weather['sys']['sunrise'].to_s,'%s')).in_time_zone("E‌​astern Time (US & Canada)").strftime("%l:%M %P") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<% time_zone = "PDT" %>
<%= Time.at(DateTime.strptime(@weather['sys']['sunrise'].to_s,'%s')).in_time_zone(time_zone).strftime("%l:%M %P") %>
```

Refer to [ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone#in_time_zone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-in_time_zone) for more info.